# Programatically install apk from assets folder in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk

I am trying to install apk programatically from assets folder but not success, Please help me. I am using following code for that. thank you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
.setData(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/youtuberanjit.apk"))
.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Akash first copy the apk file from assets to sdcard and then install apk from sdcard . I think this is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Chirag Raval : SDCARD not available in my device, I want to install apk directly from asset folder to device. Without use of sdcard...

Comment: The asset directory is just an unstructured hierarchy of files,
allowing you to put anything you want there and later retrieve as raw
byte streams.

Comment: ok but, without using sdcard is this possible to install apk. Can I use another thing or technique replace with sdcard.

Comment: You can copy it to application memory.

Comment: @Chirag Raval : Ok i will try this way... If you have helpful link for that so plz share with me.

Comment: Problem solved... first I saved apk in data/data/mypkg/myapk.apk programatically. And then start installation of apk using intent. Thank you very much for all.

Comment: @RanjitChandel have you installed the apk without copying it to the SD card. ? or ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;

try {
    in = assetManager.open("myapk.apk");
    out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/myapk.apk");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        out.write(buffer, 0, read);

    }

    in.close();
    in = null;

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/myapk.apk")),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    startActivity(intent);

} catch(Exception e) { }
```

Comment: but we need to install apk directly from assets folder. Is this possible? please help me...

Comment: yes this code is for that purpose to install from assets folder!

Comment: But this code first copy apk from asset folder and saved in sdcard... and then access from sdcard not directly assets... I want to install directly from assets to device. because sdcard not available in my device to check this code. please help me this way..

Comment: you can delete the file after copying

Comment: Is this possible without using sdcard ?

Comment: or you can do it this way 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile("file:///android_asset/myapk.apk"),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

I have not tested this!

Comment: this one is correct  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///android_asset/myapk.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Comment: its regarding to your .apk file. cross check version code name package name and all

Comment: Using this code first I saved apk in data/data/my_application_pkg/myapk.apk Then install apk from this place using INTENT. Is successfully done. Thank you very much for all answers and reply...

Comment: Hi Ranjit, Can u please explain how u saved the file in the internal memory and den installed it... Coz i did the same thing, but still getting the "problem parsing the package error"... Have i left out somthing?? Please if you can help..

Comment: this is my internal path

`/data/data/com.example.abc/files/myApkName.apk`

Comment: @RanjitChandel Hi,,I m also getting same parsing error..I am saving the apk in data/data/my_application_pkg/myapk.apk and then installing but getting the parsing error..Can u please help me out to resolve this issue...

Comment: @RanjitChande Hi, I am getting **Parse error**. Saved the apk in application dir( /data/data/<package>/files/ . My device OS is Marshmallow.

Answer (score -4):

Copy the apk file into assets folder.

try this method it worked for me ..........

```
private void launchComponent(String packageName, String name) { 

  // Name should be starting activity complete name with package name
        Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
        launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        this.startActivity(launch_intent);
    }
```