# How do I distribute apps created using ARCore in the store?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am trying to create an app using arcore-unity-sdk-preview, which is supported by Google.

However, in order to use this ARCore, arcore-preview.apk must be installed. Otherwise, ARCore will stop working.

If I distribute the app I created in the store, the user will not be able to use the app unless I receive the arcore-preview.apk. Is there a solution to this problem?

Or are still experiencing this issue because it's not fully released yet?

If know about this, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packaging ARCore Unity Projects for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958123/packaging-arcore-unity-projects-for-distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, distribution is still an issue because it's not fully released.

To work around this issue, you could upload the apk somewhere / ship it in your app's files and [install it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android) but the user has to allow installation of apps from unknown sources (`Settings > Security > Unknown Sources`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I will wait for the official distribution.